# Sort db alphabetically with header in django

Tags: python, html, django

Writing website on django:

i've got 1500 rows in DB

Need to give those rows to frontend like:

A
    Alice
    Andrew
    Ann
B
    Bill
    Boris
    Brendan
...

now in my views.py the for cycle goes around names and if the first letter of name is in the alphabet, that letter is added to my new alphabet:

```
for name in names:
  if name[0] in alphabet:
    my_alphabet.append(name[0])
my_alphabet = sorted(list(set(my_alphabet)))
```

Then I transfer my new alphabet and names to the html template:

```
{% for letter in my_alphabet %}
  <span>{{ letter }}</span>
  {% for name in names %}
    {% if name.0 == letter %}
      <span>{{ name }}</span>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That pages loads up to 10 seconds

Maybe anyone's got a faster variant?

Thanks for helping noob, sorry for wasting time!

Comment: your `django` for loop runs tooo many times about 26*1500 instead just sort them in db and use just one for loop that will print the *first next* letter whenever it encounters one and you don't need the first loop to create `alphabet`

Comment: another thing to keep in mind is that if the page will have to much data in it the browser will be very slow. but if you just display 1500 spans this should be fine. otherwise i suggest you to use pagination

Comment: What is `names`? Is it a queryset can you share how this list is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in template tag [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) can be used to loop through a list/queryset and group by a common attribute.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr
objects = MyModel.objects.order_by('name').annotate(
    first_letter=Substr('name', 1, 1)
)
```

The above queryset gives all `MyModel` instances annotated with the first letter of the name field. You can then use this in the `regroup` tag

```
{% regroup objects by first_letter as letters %}

{% for letter in letters %}
  <span>{{ letter.grouper }}</span>
  {% for object in letter.list %}
      <span>{{ object.name }}</span>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```